# Webscraping text is returning an empty set

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

### The code is not *scraping* the text when using Beautiful Soup FindAll as it returns an empty set. There are other issues with the code after this but at this stage I am trying to solve the first problem. I am pretty new to this so I understand the code structure may be less than ideal.  I come from a VBA background.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
#import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\mmanenica\Documents\chromedriver.exe")

#click the search button on Austenders to return all Awarded Contracts
import time
#define the starting point: Austenders Awarded Contracts search page
driver.get('https://www.tenders.gov.au/cn/search')
#Find the Search Button and return all search results
Search_Results = driver.find_element_by_name("SearchButton")
if 'inactive' in Search_Results.get_attribute('name'):
    print("Search Button not found")
    exit;
print('Search Button found')
Search_Results.click()    

#Pause code to prevent blocking by website
time.sleep(1)
i = 0
Awarded = []

#Move to the next search page by finding the Next button at the bottom of the page
#This code will need to be refined as the last search will be skipped currently.
while True:
    Next_Page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
    if 'inactive' in Next_Page.get_attribute('class'):
        print("End of Search Results")
        exit;  
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(2)
    
    #Loop through all the Detail links on the current Search Results Page
    print("Checking search results page " + str(i))
    print(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.current_url, features='lxml')
    #Find all Contract detail links in the current search results page
    Details = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'list-desc-inner'})

    for each_Contract in Details:
        #Loop through each Contract details link and scrape all the detailed 
        #Contract information page
        Details_Page = each_Contract.find('a', {'class': 'detail'}).get('href')        
        driver.get(Details_Page)
        #Scrape all the data in the Awarded Contract page
        #r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.current_url, features='lxml')
        
        #find a list of all the Contract Info (contained in the the 'Contact Heading'
        #class of the span element)
        Contract = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Contact-Heading'})
        Contract_Info = [span.get_text() for span in Contract]
        
        #find a list of all the Summary Contract info which is in the text of\
        #the 'list_desc_inner' class
        Sub = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'list_desc_inner'})
        Sub_Info = [div.get_text() for div in Sub]
        
        #Combine the lists into a unified list and append to the Awarded table
        Combined = [Contract_Info, Sub_Info]
        Awarded.append[Combined]
    
        #Go back to the Search Results page (from the Detailed Contract page)
        driver.back()
    
    #Go to the next Search Page by clicking on the Next button at the bottom of the page
    Next_Page.click()
    #

    time.sleep(3)    
    
print(Awarded.Shape)
```

Comment: Which line of code is not returning what you expect it to?

Comment: Details_Page = each_Contract.find('a', {'class': 'detail'}).get('href').  Where I am trying to return a collection of all the Detail links on the page.

Comment: There are multiple issues in the code & logic. The primary issue is that you are not passing page source to beautiful soup. driver.current_url returns only the url text. you should using  -     soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')

Comment: Probably worth removing the bold text and simply asking some variation of  "Why is my findall returning an empty set?"

Comment: They provide all results in `.xlsx` format, why not use it?

Comment: There is only limited data (8 data points) in the export functionality and I want all of the contract (about 20 data points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated, you are not actually feeding in the html source into BeautifulSoup. So first thing changed is: `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.current_url, features='lxml')` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')`

Second issue: Some of the elements there is no tag `<a>` with class=detail. So you won;t be able to get the href from a NoneType. I added a try/except to skip over when that happens (not sure if that gives your desired results though). You could also just get rid of that class, and just say `Details_Page = each_Contract.find('a').get('href')`

Next, that is only the extension of the url, you need to append the root, so:  `driver.get('https://www.tenders.gov.au' + Details_Page)`

I also do not see where you are referring to class=Contact-Heading.

You also refer to class='class': 'list-desc-inner' and one point, then 'class': 'list_desc_inner' at another. Again, I don't see a class=list_desc_inner

Next. to append a list to a list, you want `Awarded.append(Combined)`, not `Awarded.append[Combined]`

I also added `.strip()` in there to clean up some of that white space in the text.

Anyways, there's a lot you need to fix and clean up, and I also don't know what your expected output should be. But hopefully this gets you started.

Also, as stated in the comments, you COULD just click the download buttin and get the results straight away, but maybe you're doing it the hard way to practice...

```
import requests
from requests import get
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
#import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")

#click the search button on Austenders to return all Awarded Contracts
import time
#define the starting point: Austenders Awarded Contracts search page
driver.get('https://www.tenders.gov.au/cn/search')
#Find the Search Button and return all search results
Search_Results = driver.find_element_by_name("SearchButton")
if 'inactive' in Search_Results.get_attribute('name'):
    print("Search Button not found")
    exit;
print('Search Button found')
Search_Results.click()    

#Pause code to prevent blocking by website
time.sleep(1)
i = 0
Awarded = []

#Move to the next search page by finding the Next button at the bottom of the page
#This code will need to be refined as the last search will be skipped currently.
while True:
    Next_Page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
    if 'inactive' in Next_Page.get_attribute('class'):
        print("End of Search Results")
        exit;  
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(2)

    #Loop through all the Detail links on the current Search Results Page
    print("Checking search results page " + str(i))
    print(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')
    #Find all Contract detail links in the current search results page
    Details = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'list-desc-inner'})

    for each_Contract in Details:
        #Loop through each Contract details link and scrape all the detailed 
        #Contract information page
        try:
            Details_Page = each_Contract.find('a', {'class': 'detail'}).get('href')       
            driver.get('https://www.tenders.gov.au' + Details_Page)
            #Scrape all the data in the Awarded Contract page
            #r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')

            #find a list of all the Contract Info (contained in the the 'Contact Heading'
            #class of the span element)
            Contract = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Contact-Heading'})
            Contract_Info = [span.text.strip() for span in Contract]

            #find a list of all the Summary Contract info which is in the text of\
            #the 'list_desc_inner' class
            Sub = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'list-desc-inner'})
            Sub_Info = [div.text.strip() for div in Sub]

            #Combine the lists into a unified list and append to the Awarded table
            Combined = [Contract_Info, Sub_Info]
            Awarded.append(Combined)

            #Go back to the Search Results page (from the Detailed Contract page)
            driver.back()
        except:
            continue

    #Go to the next Search Page by clicking on the Next button at the bottom of the page
    Next_Page.click()
    #

    time.sleep(3)    
driver.close()
print(Awarded.Shape)
```